# How to create a beat based on metricbeat

Tags: elasticsearch, metricbeat

I'm trying to create a beat based on metricbeat:
https://github.com/fdmsantos/vspherebeat

I followed this documentation : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/devguide/current/creating-beat-from-metricbeat.html

**Error:**

```
./vspherebeat Exiting: error loading config file: stat beat.yml: no such file or director
```

I can't understand Why the beat look to beat.yml file and not vspherebeat.yml?

The file vspherebeat.yml exists and was created by the command make update

Comment: I'd suggest you sharing some more information, such as: yml file (just to verify that is correct), file directory. This is to help people troubleshooting the issue

Comment: Hi, tks for the answer/help. All files are in https://github.com/fdmsantos/vspherebeat

Comment: @FDS Any help on this? Were you able to solve this issue? I am facing the same exception.